# Number of rational points of $C:y^5=-x^2+x$ over $ \Bbb{F}_5$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry, abelian-varieties

Let $C:y^5=-x^2+x$ be a super ellipticcurve over $\Bbb{Q}$.

I counted up the point of $ \sharp C( \Bbb{F}_5)$ and obtained $C( \Bbb{F}_5)=6$.
I want to know what $ \sharp C( \Bbb{F}_{25})$ is.
I guess this is $36$ using congruent zeta function.Numerator of congruent zeta function of $C$ is, I think, $(1+5X)^2$, so I think $ \sharp C( \Bbb{F}_{25})=(1+5・１)^2=36$. But I don't have confident, so I want to confirm the result.

But I couldn't find this curve in LMFDB(Maybe my searching skill is not good),
thank you for your help.

Comment: Swap $x$ and $y$ and this curve is hyperelliptic, isomorphic to $y^2 =x^5 + \frac14$. You can find it [here](https://www.lmfdb.org/Genus2Curve/Q/3125/a/3125/1)

Comment: Oh my god, thank you. I'm bad at finding curves in LMFDB. Do you know some knack?

Comment: In this case, it was a matter of realising that the curve was genus 2, and plugging it into the search bar under "Genus 2 curves over Q"

Comment: Thank you. But I want to know $ \Bbb{F_{25}}$  rational points and I cannot see the results in your linked page, where can I see the results ?

Comment: You can try looking at the attached L-function. Although the curve does have bad reduction at 5..

Comment: I'm confused, by isom $ \Bbb{Z}[ζ_5]/(1-ξ_5) \cong  \Bbb{F}_5$, $ζ_5 $ and $-ζ_5$ corresponds to $1,3$ respectively, then reduction curve is $y^5=3x^2+x/  \Bbb{F}_5$ is nonsingular. For hyperelliptic curves, is it true that 'to have good reduction' is equivalent to 'not divide discriminant' ?

Comment: By the way, LMFDB has corner 'Abelian varieties over $ \Bbb{F}_q$, can I search this hyperelliptic curve in this corner ?

Comment: The fact that the conductor of the Jacobian is 3125, which is divisible by 5, means that the Jacobian, and hence the curve, has bad reduction. You have to be careful at $5$, in exactly the same way you have to be careful at $2$ and $3$ for elliptic curves. I'm not sure I understand your calculation, but over $\mathbb F_5$, $y^5 = -x^2+x$ is isomorphic to $y^2 = x^5-1 = (x-1)^5$.

Comment: It is immediate that the affine curve $y^5=-x^2+x$ has $5^n$ points over $\Bbb{F}_{5^n}$ (the $(a,(-a^2+a)^{5^{n-1}})$)

Comment: At the level of function fields this is a purely inseparable extension of $\Bbb{F}_5(x)$, so some tools may not work in the usual way. I guess that is just one of the ways bad reduction manifests itself.